# Kotlin: Higher-order functions to count the amount of occurrences in a List?

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to use Kotlin's higher-order functions to count how many times a specific element is contained in a list. I have tried something like

```
val result: Int? = list.count{ list.contains("element") }
```

but it seems that is returning the size of the list, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You check if the list contains a given element (which will either result in `0` or the list's size) though what you actually want is to count the number of elements that are equal to the given element (not to the whole list).

What you need to do is to change `list.contains("element")` to `it == "element"`.

The `count` function works by iterating over the list and checks if the element matches the predicate.
Approximated code

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.count(predicate: (T) -> Boolean) {
     var count = 0    

     for (element in this) {
        if (predicate(this)) {
            count += 1
        }
    }

    return count
}
```

When you pass `list.contains("element")` as the parameter then the `count` function either returns 0 or `list.size` because it checks the same thing `list.size` times.

Doing `it == "element"` though works differently. Instead of checking the whole list you only check the current element. If you are coming from a Java background it might be easier for you to think of `it` as this: in Java you'd have code looking somewhat like this `(element) -> element.equals("element")` though in Kotlin if you have a higher-order function with only 1 parameter and don't explicitly name it then it defaults to `it`. You can read a bit more about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter).